# Find a method of moments estimator of the survival function $S(t)=P(X>t)$ for a given $t>\mu$

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. observations from a location-scale family of exponential distributions with the pdf $$f_X(x|\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}exp(-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}), x\geq \mu \text{ and } \sigma>0$$ Assuming both parameters are unknown, find a method of moments estimator of the survival function $S(t)=P(X>t)$ for a given $t>\mu$, assuming that $X$ follows the pdf above.

I don't seem to have any idea how to start. Can I get help just starting the problem?

Answer (score 0):

$S(t) = P(X>t) = E[1_{X>t}]$.  This is the first population moment.
Thus: set $S(t)$ estimate  = sample mean of $1_{X_i > t}$.